# How do you disable the "Save as draft" button shown when creating a blog post?

Tags: blog, draft

How do you disable the "Save as draft" button shown when creating a blog post?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable content approval setting in list versioning settings to achieve this:

[image: content approval setting]

Comment: it didn't help to me. I created the task list with approving form by "User collect data" workflow and in this list I set "No" by this howto, but the [Save draft] button was not hidden. I created the how-to for user with "DON'T USE THIS BUTTON", but users usually didn't use manuals :-) and the button Save... looks better then Complette... for them. Do you have an idea? L